# Compile error in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: compile, arduino-pro-micro, compilation-errors

I'm trying to compile a code to arudino pro micro, I have the right option for compiling like the port and the type of the board,but I get an error,I can't copy

[image: error message]

Comment: did you start with Arduino on Linux now? did it ever work? did you set the access right to USB port?

Comment: Welcome to Arduino Stack Exchange. you have a issue about `include <keyboard.h>` . What your the library using?

Comment: I open arduino ide using ubuntu,this is my first time compile a code in linux

Comment: then please read the "Please read" for Linux https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Linux#toc6

Comment: And I believe I chose the correct port

Comment: Did you join the dialout group as instructed in the guide?

Comment: post your code in proper tags, not an image.  Please read Arduino SE tour if you don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely a permission problem.  The user likely does not have permission to read from and write to the port created when plugging in the Arduino.  This can be temporally fixed using the following command:

```
sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyACM0
```

However, this procedure is only temporary as the port is recreated every time the Arduino is reconnected to the computer.  And upon recreation the permissions are reset to their defaults for security reasons.

A better solution is to determine the group which the port belongs to and to add the users expected to access these connected devices to that group.

Plugin and list the port to determine its group:

```
ls -l /dev/ttyACM*
```

or

```
ls -l /dev/ttyUSB*
```

The group the ports belong to will likely be "dialout".  Add the user to that group:

```
usermod -a -G dialout user_name
```

...where user_name is replaced by the name of the user who needs access to the port.  If you don't know the name of the current user you can use this command:

```
whoami
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply,it worked in the ide that I download from the web,apparently ide from the ubuntu software won't work.
Thank for the answer

Comment: It's not the new IDE. It's the setup script that comes bundled with it that [issues the `usermod` command](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/1.8.9/build/linux/dist/arduino-linux-setup.sh#L77) suggested by st2000.